# 3D Camera Rotation in OpenGL: How to prevent camera jitter?

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation, jogl, quaternions

I'm fairly new to OpenGL and 3D programming but I've begun to implement camera rotation using quaternions based on the tutorial from http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html . This is all written in Java using JOGL.

I realise these kind of questions get asked quite a lot but I've been searching around and can't find a solution that works so I figured it might be a problem with my code specifically.

So the problem is that there is jittering and odd rotation if I do two different successive rotations on one or more axis. The first rotation along the an axis, either negatively or positively, works fine. However, if I rotate positively along the an axis and then rotate negatively on that axis then the rotation will jitter back and forth as if it was alternating between doing a positive and negative rotation.

If I automate the rotation, (e.g. rotate left 500 times then rotate right 500 times) then it appears to work properly which led me to think this might be related to the keypresses. However, the rotation is also incorrect (for lack of a better word) if I rotate around the x axis and then rotate around the y axis afterwards.

Anyway, I have a renderer class with the following display loop for drawing `scene nodes':

```
private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(70, Constants.viewWidth / Constants.viewHeight, 0.1, 30000);
    gl.glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); //flip the y axis

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    camera.rotateCamera();
    glu.gluLookAt(camera.getCamX(), camera.getCamY(), camera.getCamZ(), camera.getViewX(), camera.getViewY(), camera.getViewZ(), 0, 1, 0);
    drawSceneNodes(gl);
}

private void drawSceneNodes(GL2 gl) {
    if (currentEvent != null) {
        ArrayList<SceneNode> sceneNodes = currentEvent.getSceneNodes();
        for (SceneNode sceneNode : sceneNodes) {
            sceneNode.update(gl);
        }
    }

    if (renderQueue.size() > 0) {
        currentEvent = renderQueue.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Rotation is performed in the camera class as follows:

```
public class Camera {
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private double rotation = 0;

    private Vector3D cam = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
    private Vector3D view = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
    private Vector3D axis = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

    private Rotation total = new Rotation(0, 0, 0, 1, true);

    public Camera(GL2 gl, Vector3D cam, Vector3D view, int width, int height) {
        this.cam = cam;
        this.view = view;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void rotateCamera() {
        if (rotation != 0) {
            //generate local quaternion from new axis and new rotation
            Rotation local = new Rotation(Math.cos(rotation/2), Math.sin(rotation/2 * axis.getX()), Math.sin(rotation/2 * axis.getY()), Math.sin(rotation/2 * axis.getZ()), true);

            //multiply local quaternion and total quaternion
            total = total.applyTo(local);

            //rotate the position of the camera with the new total quaternion
            cam = rotatePoint(cam);

            //set next rotation to 0
            rotation = 0;
        }
    }

    public Vector3D rotatePoint(Vector3D point) {
        //set world centre to origin, i.e. (width/2, height/2, 0) to (0, 0, 0)
        point = new Vector3D(point.getX() - width/2, point.getY() - height/2, point.getZ());

        //rotate point
        point = total.applyTo(point);

        //set point in world coordinates, i.e. (0, 0, 0) to (width/2, height/2, 0) 
        return new Vector3D(point.getX() + width/2, point.getY() + height/2, point.getZ());
    }

    public void setAxis(Vector3D axis) {
        this.axis = axis;
    }

    public void setRotation(double rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

The method rotateCamera generates the new permenant quaternions from the new rotation and previous rotations while the method rotatePoint merely multiplies a point by the rotation matrix generated from the permenant quaternion.

The axis of rotation and the angle of rotation are set by simple key presses as follows:

```
    @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        camera.setAxis(new float[] {1, 0, 0});
        camera.setRotation(0.1f);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        camera.setAxis(new float[] {0, 1, 0});
        camera.setRotation(0.1f);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        camera.setAxis(new float[] {1, 0, 0});
        camera.setRotation(-0.1f);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        camera.setAxis(new float[] {0, 1, 0});
        camera.setRotation(-0.1f);
    }
}
```

I hope I've provided enough detail. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

About the jittering: I don't see any render loop in your code. How is the render method triggered? By a timer or by an event?

Your messed up rotations when rotating about two axes are probably related to the fact that you need to rotate the axis of the second rotation along with the total rotation of the first axis. You cannot just apply the rotation about the X or Y axis of the global coordinate system. You must apply the rotation about the up and right axes of the camera.

I suggest that you create a camera class that stores the up, right and view direction vectors of the camera and apply your rotations directly to those axes. If this is an FPS like camera, then you'll want to rotate the camera horizontally (looking left / right) about the absolute Y axis and not the up vector. This will also result in a new right axis of the camera. Then, you rotate the camera vertically (looking up / down) about the new right axis. However, you must be careful when the camera looks directly up or down, as in this case you can't use the cross product of the view direction and up vectors to obtain the right vector.

Comment: The SceneRenderer class implements GLEventListener contains display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) which calls render() and hence the render loop. The model side of the application just passes update events and they're then stored in the render queue. Sorry for not being clearer.

The Camera class already stores the position of the eye and what its looking at (I'll add the code to the original post).

As to the vector defining the up direction. Does this need to change as the camera is rotated? I assumed if you use gluLookAt() after rotating the pos of the cam that the up direction wouldn't change.

Comment: I should of explained that this is a 3rd person camera that orbits around a fixed point. The point being looked doesn't change on rotation, only if the camera is translated but that's entirely separate. Is it not enough to just rotate the position of the camera? Sorry if I'm being stupid. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the first thing you should do is use a proper vector math library, because your rotation code is pretty hard to understand. You should have classes for 3D vectors and quaternions that perform the actual work, instead of implementing everything inside your camera. In its current state, it's pretty hard to say what your code actually does and whether it does it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too early. Here's the rest:

Now I also understand why you were supplying the coordinate system axes as the rotation axes. However, you still need to use the local coordinate system axes of the camera as explained above. Otherwise, your object will not be in the center of rotation anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I moved everything over to using the Apache Commons library and managed to solve the problem: it was due to the way I was applying the new rotation quaternion.